# Using Bayesian statistics to analyze food production

Tags: r, regression, bayesian

I am in the process of learning about Bayesian statistics with the help of R, and I would like to know the kind of analysis questions I should pose. 
Say for instance, with this [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bjfr3pgiqEHWgIGiu6OKVKP8X4d0yDgKkpUKF2mx8l0/edit?usp=sharing) of food production in various countries. So far, I've just created simple linear regression models.

Comment: It is unclear what is your question about. If you ask "kind of analysis questions I should pose", than the answer is simple and useless: you should ask questions that are *relevant* to your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to stretch your wings a bit you might try picking up a book on bayesian analysis, maybe even written in a different language and work through some examples.

What immediately comes to mind would be:

R: [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/exercises)

Python: [Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers)

If you are looking for relevant Bayesian questions in your work I suppose you need to provide more detail about what you do/are trying to do. This would be more of evaluating if a Bayesian Approach is relevant though.